# Clicking through carousel image in protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, testing, protractor

I have a carousel image which varies depends on the customer GUID I am viewing. So far I have made this work. But when I put that in the for loop, it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
var date = element(by.css('i.icon.left-arrow'));
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(date), 30000, "Date Range is still not clickable");
date.click(); // This works but this will go back only once.
```

I have this for loop: To identify all the elements and click through the image. Is this correct way of identifying in angular? Please advise.

```
var backArrow = element.all(by.css('i.icon.left-arrow'));
for (var i=0;i<backArrow.length;i++) {
    backArrow.click();
}
```

Here is the element: This depends on the customer I am viewing. The images can vary anywhere between 1 to 50:

```
<i class="icon left-arrow"></i>
```

Answer (score 1):

To apply a function to every element in the `ElementArrayFinder`, use [`each()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each):

```
element.all(by.css('i.icon.left-arrow')).each(function (arrow) {
    arrow.click();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.It is clicking only one arrow back. Not all of them. Any idea?

Comment: @user2744620 are you getting any errors? Are you sure there are multiple elements matching `i.icon.left-arrow` css selector? Thanks.

Comment: No, I am not getting any error. Yes, that arrow mark is there on each page. Once I click on left the image goes to the next image and the same left arrow appears. Does that treated as next page element?

Comment: @user2744620 correct me if I'm wrong. You mean that each time there is only one element matching `i.icon.left-arrow`? This is a game changer then, please confirm.

Comment: @user2744620 thanks, when the page is opened, how would you know how much icons like this you need to click? (if possible, provide an HTML code samples). Thanks!

Comment: As I understand, there is only one element with that ID at any point in time on your website; therefore that's why this is not working. You will need to click multiple times on THE SAME element, not loop through a single element ID. Try calling date.click() multiple times and add a small wait in between, just to make sure it works.

Comment: This is what I can find. I also have public url which I can share it with you, Is there a way I can directly send the link only to you if that is Okay?<symbol id="icon-left-arrow" viewBox="0 0 30 30">
<title>left-arrow</title>
<path d="M22.1 29.7c.1 0 .3 0 .4-.1.2-.2.2-.5 0-.7L8.6 15 22.4 1.2c.2-.2.2-.5 0-.7-.2-.2-.5-.2-.7 0L7.5 14.6c-.1.1-.1.2-.1.4 0 .1.1.3.1.4l14.3 14.2c.1.1.2.1.3.1z">

Comment: I am just calling the same backarrow 5 times and making sure the graph is not broken